# Radio buttons not working... Unless they are in an iframe

Tags: html, inheritance, radio-button

I am trying to make an HTML document that contains radio buttons. This document is ***not intended for a browser***, rather an external program that we work in.

I developed the HTML first outside of the program and tested it in my browser, and it works as intended.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5dn3zbt/

However, inside the program this document behaves oddly. Once a set of radio buttons is clicked, the chosen option cannot be unclicked and the unchosen option cannot be clicked. This happens per set of radio buttons, so using the JSFiddle as example, once you choose True for Question 1 you cannot switch to False, the same then happens with Question 2.

Trying to debug the issue I went with the hypothesis that some inherited functionality was causing this behavior so I saved the HTML document as an external .html file and made the internal HTML render an iframe with the src set to that file

`<iframe src="file://C:/HTML/TestingRadio.html"></iframe>`

and the radio buttons now function exactly as expected inside the iframe.

I'd much rather avoid the iframe workaround as it will complicate getting the chosen responses more difficult and require creating a file to render rather than just rendering the HTML internally.

Is there any simple solution to find out what is being inherited that would break the radio buttons?

```css
.question {
  color: black;
  font-family: "calibri";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.quizTitle {
  color: black;
  font-family: "calibri";
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="quizTitle">
    True/False Quiz
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="question" id="1">
    1. True or false?
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="1-1" name="1" value="true">
    <label for="1-1">
   True
  </label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="1-2" name="1" value="false">
    <label for="1-2">
   False
  </label>
    <br>
  </p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="question" id="2">
    2. True or false?
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="2-1" name="2" value="true">
    <label for="2-1">
   True
  </label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="2-2" name="2" value="false">
    <label for="2-2">
   False
  </label>

    <br>
  </p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="question" id="3">
    3. True or false?
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="3-1" name="3" value="true">
    <label for="3-1">
   True
  </label>

    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="3-2" name="3" value="false">
    <label for="3-2">
   False
  </label>
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code runs as expected here and in the JSFiddle

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, exactly as I describe in my post the code works fine in a browser but not in the program that I am working in. The program isn't publicly available it is a licensed program to corporations that has no public advice forum so I am posting here. I am looking for "breadcrumbs" on what could be being inherited from the program's global HTML/CSS/JS that could be breaking the radio buttons, assuming that the iframe being treated as a diff. document and not inheriting the program's HTML/CSS/JS is what is causing the radio buttons to work as expected when in an iframe.

Comment: "the program" was not very clear in the description. Try to wrap the labels around the radios, then you do not need IDs and perhaps the IDs are taken by "the program" as separate naming items in which case the radio "names" are all different